# How to Identify a websites audience

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I'm trying to identify web traffic based on the country the person is from.

Obviously I can do this if they are searching my website from their own country.

But what if they are visiting another country while on holiday.

Is there a way to capture anything so I can know its a tourist and not a local.

E.g. maybe the country a mobile device is registered in? Or some other piece of data?

Comment: Just a thought, maybe you could make a custom report based on User location and compare against their browser language setting. Eg I speak english, if I were overseas for business/vacation etc, I would still be browsing in en-us